# Cycle start node of Cycle linked list

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a program for finding a starting node of circular linked list. My code is-

```
struct node
{
char data;
struct node *link;
} ;

char FindStartNode(struct node **q)
{
    struct node *r,*t;
 r = *q; 
 t = *q;
 while(t->link != NULL)
 {
     r = r->link;
     t = t->link->link;
     if(r == t)
     {
         break;
     }
 }
 if(t == NULL )
     return NULL;
 r = *q;
 while(r != t)
 {
     t = t->link;
     r = r->link;
 }
 return t->data;
}


int main()
{
struct node *p;
p = NULL;
char num;
Append(&p,'A');
Append(&p,'B');
Append(&p,'C');
Append(&p,'D');
Append(&p,'E');
Append(&p,'C');
Display(p);
 num = FindStartNode(&p);
printf("\nStarting node of the cycle linked list is:- %c",num);
_getch();
return 0;
}


int Append(struct node **q, char data)
{
struct node *r,*t;
r = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
r->data = data;
r->link = NULL;
if(*q == NULL)
    *q = r;
else
{
  t = *q;
  while(t->link != NULL)
  {
      t = t->link;
  }
  t->link = r;
    }
return 0;
}
int Display(struct node *q)
{
while(q != NULL)
{
    printf("%c\t",q->data);
    q = q->link;
}
return 0;
}
```

ths is my code. I'm not getting any value in return t->data part or I'm unable to find the start node of cycle ink list.Any help?

Comment: Is this code intended to determine if a list happens to be circle back to somewhere in the list (ie., that a node is linked in twice)? If so and assuming that you fix the `NULL` dereference that seems to be leading to this question, then it appears that you might get stuck in the last `while` loop with `r` endlessly chasing `t`.

Comment: Isn't the very idea of a "starting node" in a circular linked list somewhat... arbitrary? I thought they *all* could be a start-node. Or are you intended on finding the node that points *to the one you have* ? Are we to assume that `*q` has a pointer to *some* node, and the one you want is the one *before* it ?

Comment: What does that even mean, finding the starting node for a circular list? The code for creating the list ought to provide a pointer to an element, almost always the first one created. That's the entry point. After that, there is no real start or end, conceptually. That's why it's circular.

Comment: Darn it, WhozCraig, ya beat me to it.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think he wants to find the node which has a **broken** pointer to a node previously mentioned on the list - thus making it a circular list -

Comment: @HackSaw trust me, I'm sure the "huh?" was as loud on your side as it was here.

Comment: @Aposperite I must have put too many hours in today, because I'm still not following. A circ-ll has no breaks, even a single-node list is self-pointing. I hate to ask, by "broken" you mean.. ? (Not being a smartass, I'm just now following, hope you understand.)

Comment: @HackSaw -problem solved, but in return t->data part I'm not getting any value.any solution??

Comment: There you'd need to show us the code making the list.

Comment: @WhozCraig Maybe I can give you an example, suppose we have this list `2,6,3,1,5,3,1,5,3,1,5...` In this list, the *broken* pointer is the one pointing right after 5-> as it points to 3 etc, **this** is where the list gets circular.

Comment: Those are just assumptions I am making, I am not sure what the OP means though...

Comment: @Aposperite Hey I'm with you, sir. I *think* I understand now, though. Nice example. would be nice if the OP chimed in to confirm it.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to implement the `Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm` AKA `the tortoise and the hare algorithm`. You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare).

Comment: where is "node" defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 t = t->link->link; // t->link can be null 
   //so t = t->link->link can be a crash or illegal reference
```

Change the loop to:

```
 while(t != NULL)
 {
     r = r->link;
     t = t->link;
     if(t == NULL)
       break; // or return no circle
     else t = t->link;
     if(r == t)
     {
         break;
     }
 }
```

I have gone through your code. Comparing with the algorithm discussion [here](http://umairsaeed.com/2011/06/23/finding-the-start-of-a-loop-in-a-circular-linked-list/) it seems to be OK. But you are returning a `char` why dont you return a pointer so that you can check if it is NULL or not. In case it is not null then issue pt->tada. This makes more sense.

I checked you code it seems you are not implementing circular linked list correctly in `Append()`. I am providing you with a working implementation below.  See how I modified `Append()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
char data;
struct node *link;
} ;

char FindStartNode(struct node **q)
{
    struct node *r,*t;
 r = *q;
 t = *q;
 while(t->link != NULL)
 {
     r = r->link;
     t = t->link->link;
     if(r == t)
     {
         break;
     }
 }
 if(t == NULL )
     return NULL;
 r = *q;
 while(r != t)
 {
     t = t->link;
     r = r->link;
 }
 return t->data;
}

int Append(struct node **q, char data);
int main()
{
struct node *p;
p = NULL;
char num;
Append(&p,'A');
Append(&p,'B');
Append(&p,'C');
Append(&p,'D');
Append(&p,'E');
Append(&p,'C');
//Display(p);
 num = FindStartNode(&p);
printf("\nStarting node of the cycle linked list is:- %c\n",num);
//_getch();
return 0;
}

int Append(struct node **q, char data)
{

struct node *r,*t, *startOfcycle=NULL;
r = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
r->data = data;


r->link = NULL;
if(*q == NULL)
    *q = r;
else
{
  t = *q;
  while(t->link != NULL)
  {
      if(t->data == data)
         startOfcycle = t;

      t = t->link;
  }


  if(startOfcycle == NULL)
  t->link = r;
  else {// there is a cycle point to the start of cycle
     t->link = startOfcycle;
     free(r);
  }
    }
return 0;
}
int Display(struct node *q)
{
while(q != NULL)
{
    printf("%c\t",q->data);
    q = q->link;
}
```

Please note that `Display` function is also wrong as runs an infinite loop of the linked list is circular. I have not modified it since it is not relevant to you question. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, you are right I'm facing same problem but how can i ignore that?

Comment: Please look at my code I have added appropriate portion of code to modify.

Comment: In return t->data ,I'm not getting any value.it should return the start node.why so?

Comment: Oh, no, t->data ought not give you back the starting node, only link might do that, unless you stored the starting node pointer into the data of a node.

Comment: but before return t->data , I tried to print the value of t->data within that function, but that is also not showing any value.

Answer (score 0):

...

```
 p = NULL;
 char num;
 Append(&p,'A');
```

...

You are trying to assign to NULL, which Append handles, but you are doing it repeatedly, which means you won't make a list, just a bunch of dangling nodes.

You need to make one node to start, outside of append, as your seed node, and pass that in.